# why ng-show not working correctly in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to show a drop down when user click on icon .I use `ng-show` but it is not displaying the  drop down menu option.

- I make a icon `...` .on click I try to open drop down menu using ng-show .but it not displaying why ?

here is my code

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/pbPJEN

```
$scope.showDropDown=function(e){
    alert('show drop down');
    $scope.showDropDown=true;
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show='showDropDown'>
                    <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>

                </ul>
```

Comment: If you want a toggle effect, @AsimKT 's solution is okay. I'd also recommend you to check angular-strap, which is a wonderful angular bootstrap implementation. You don't need to write such logic by you own at all.

Comment: I would suggest you to give distinct name for ng-click and ng-show. It will be very confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You should call the action to set the `$scope.showDropDown` in ng-click. ie use a function to set the value.

**JS**

```
 $scope.showDropDownFunction = function(e){
    alert('show drop down');
    $scope.showDropDown=true;
    // as stanleyxu2005 said if you want a toggle effect (hide/show)
    // menu on each click, use
    //$scope.showDropDown= !$scope.showDropDown; 
    //instead
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <button ng-click='showDropDownFunction()'> show menu </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show='showDropDown'>
   <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
 </ul>
```

So what's happening here is we show the ul when clicking on button.

See the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
PS: checkout the last example.

Comment: Once `showDropDown` is to `true`, it will never reset to `false`. Are you sure this gonna work?

Comment: Author of question want to know why ng-show didn't worked. I tried to conserve the original code. Otherwise `$scope.showDropDown=!$scope.showDropDown;` will be good to toggle the visibility of menu. I edited the answer. :)

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle or plunker. The dropdown are not at all visible

Comment: Sorry, changed showDropDownFunction to showDropDownFunction(). https://plnkr.co/edit/560L7xqgn05mC8eTyLgC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

no need to declare a function

```
 <button ng-click="showDropDown=true" >Show Drop Down</button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="showDropDown">
     <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
 </ul>
```